# Windows doubles my quote input across multiple keyboard layout

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I've tried to look for an answer and I really couldn't find anything.

I use US-International keyboard layout. I code but I work in a French based company so it's a useful layout to type in French and also access special characters easily.

The problem is the following: every time I press a single quote character, it's doubled. I've tried multiple keyboard layouts and it's the same behavior. When I press the single quote ONCE, it outputs : ''. If I press the double quote: '".

Also, I don't have this problem on my remote desktop, so I know the problem is local on my computer and software based.

This is very problematic for my work and any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the source of the problem was "Dell Display Manager". The moment I uninstalled it, the problem went away.

The curious thing is that Dell Display Manager doesn't have any keyboard related features except a couple of shortcuts for Display related functions. None that would include the quote characters.